# Creating multiple subviews inside view controller

Tags: objective-c

I have a view controller named ViewController.

- ViewController displays a UIView that has a button on it, which allows me to advance to a second view controller - SecondViewController.
- SecondViewController also has a button on it, which allows me to advance to a third view controller.

However, I am having trouble displaying ThirdViewController.  When I tap the button in  SecondViewController it throws an error:

> Warning: Attempt to present ... on ... whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

I have been to a bunch of other sites and posts that address this issue, but cannot seem to find a working solution.  I have implemented quite a few solutions, but none seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)secondaryView:(UIView *)secondaryView
{
    UIView *theView = secondaryView;

    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;

    [viewController.view addSubview:theView];
    viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

`secondaryView` is a UIView that I am constructing elsewhere in the application.  I add it to the viewController then present the `viewController`.

Is there any way to dynamically create UIViewControllers, add a UIView to each one, and add them to the window hierarchy?

Comment: This is not how you do it. Just instantiate the next controller, and present it. You don't add its view as a subview.

Comment: secondaryView is a separate view that I am constructing elsewhere and want to add it to the new ViewController.  Sorry if that was not clear, I will make an edit to the post.  Either way, I tried your solution, and unfortunately it did not fix my problem.

Comment: What controller is the code you posted in? Is that controller's view on screen when you tap the button?

Comment: Can you use navigation in your viewControllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use navigation in your ViewControllers, you can try the below code

In the place where you call the firstViewController,

```
   -(void)callFirst
    {
    FirstViewController *first = [FirstViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:first];
    navigationController.modalPresentaionStyle = UIModalPresenationFormSheet;
    [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
}
```

And in the FirstViewController button action ,you can write

```
-(void)callSec
{
SecondViewController *sec = [SecondViewController alloc] init];
[self.NavigationController pushViewController:sec animated:YES];
}
```

And in SecondViewController you can do the same

```
  -(void)callThird
    {
        ThirdViewController *third = [ThirdViewController alloc] init];
        [self.NavigationController pushViewController:third animated:YES];

    }
```

Try this...And in these ViewControllers you can do whatever coding you want to meet the requirement like

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,400,400)];
newView.backGroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubView:newView];
}
```